# Can I generate bindings for one class only in Xamarin.Android binding library project?

Tags: binding, xamarin.android

I'm trying to write Xamarin binding library for a native android library. I was wondering if it might be able to "tell" Visual Studio which classes/files from the native library I would like to bridge? At this moment Visual Studio is generating bindings for all classes. Can I somehow avoid this and generate bindings only for one?

Comment: Sure, use the `<remove-node>` transformation. https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb#removing-types

Comment: But that's after you built the project, right?

Comment: It's during the build process when the nodes will be considered. So your two options would be:

1. Make a wrapper that exposes the items you want bound.
2. Remove the excess items you don't want bound.